# How to let shell sh known ksh's environment variable

Tags: shell, environment-variables, aix

system: AIX6

default shell is ksh

in ~/.profile, set the env var MFE_HOME:

MFE_HOME=/home/mfe/MFE

then exec some shell scripts, "sh xxx.sh", which will judge $MFE_HOME exists or not,
and it finds not.

-----> how to let it find ~/.profile 's env var $MFE_HOME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the environment variable so that it is inherited/available to sub shells.  Add `export MFE_HOME` in your *.profile*.